# How can I replace part of a timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, replace, timestamp

In VBA Excel, I would like to replace timestamps that contain 00:00:00 in the H:m:s part with the value 00:00:01. The full format of the timestamp used is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

When I try using a simple find and replace, it does not work. I think because the format is a Timestamp and as such it does not recognize this as a string.

Comment: Please make sure that in Find Replace Options, Match entire cell contents is unchecked.

Comment: *replace timestamps that contain 00:00:00 in the H:m:s part with the value 00:00:01* Not sure what you mean. Can you post an example?

Comment: Any timestamp that contains 00:00:00 I want to replace with the same date, but change the time to 00:00:01

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the formatting of the cell, the `value` in excel is the same.

Select the cells you want to display in a certain way, go to format -> Custom ->

**Type:**

> hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

If these are not `String` data type but actual numeric values formatted as you describe, you could check:

***Per formula:***

```
IF(HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)+SECOND(A1)=0,A1+1/86400,A1)
```

*Or:*

```
IF(INT(A1)=A1,A1+1/86400,A1)
```

***Per Code:***

```
If Hour([A1]) + Minute([A1]) + Second([A1]) = 0 Then Range("A1").Value = [A1+1/86400]
```

*Or:*

```
If Int([A1]) = [A1] Then Range("A1").Value = [A1+1/86400]
```

---

In the above, change `[A1]` for your variable holding the date-time value, and create an explicit `Range` reference.

Comment: I think this points me in the right direction. The output I now create however is #NAME?   Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @AnoukMaaskant, I recon you are Dutch? Then use the Dutch equivalent: `=ALS(UUR(A1)+MINUUT(A1)+SECONDE(A1)=0;A1+1/86400;A1)` =). Also, if this has helped, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: Or: `=ALS(INTEGER(A1)=A1;A1+1/86400;A1)`

Comment: @AnoukMaaskant, any luck on this? If this has answered your question. You should accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, no. My Excel is in English so changing the formula names does not help. I will however close the topic now, since I have moved from VBA to another solution alltogether. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To anyone still looking for the answer; in my new chosen method (PowerBI query editor), I change the type to text, do the replace and then revert the type to Datetime. Not pretty but it works